# Purpose of .query in python

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to understand the code used in my new job's web-application. In their `models.py` file, I see that they call a lot of classes with the `.query` method, which will then be set equal to a new variable. For example:

```
def child_variant(self):
    #for checking if the current variant is an original variant and has a child variant (the hidden variant record) and if so returning it
    child_variant = Variant.query.filter(Variant.original_variant_id==self.id).first()
    if child_variant:
        return child_variant
    else:
        return False
```

I am not sure if the `.query` method has a special purpose, for example running through their database, and is referring to a sort of SQL command, or if it is referring to some sort of jQuery command.

Comment: It's an ORM (object-relational mapper) query. In other words, there is a layer of abstraction between the application and the database.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps, yeah! I was wondering how the code connected with the db

Comment: No worries, man. Good luck sorting it out.

Comment: And anyone who views this, please feel free to rank my question up or down. I want to improve in my question asking, I am still new to stackoverflow 